Gaussian blur with variable standard deviation
I'm trying to find fast ways to evaluate the following integral defined over points $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2$:
$$\Phi(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2(\mathbf{x})}\int d^2y\, \exp\left(-\frac{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|^2}{2\sigma^2(\mathbf{x})}\right)\phi(\mathbf{y}).$$
Here $\phi(\mathbf{x})$ is a smooth function, which one might assume represents an image. This almost looks like a Gaussian blur, except for the fact that the standard deviation $\sigma(\mathbf{x})$ depends on the coordinate $\mathbf{x}$.  Because this equation isn't a convolution, I can't directly use FFT based methods.
Are there fast methods to evaluate such integrals numerically?

Probably depends on the specific function for std deviation. What is it?

$\sigma(\mathbf{x})$ is a smooth function.  It can be made periodic, but apart from that I want to keep it general.

This seems like it could be accomplished in scale space  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_space
where $\sigma^2(\mathbf x)$ is a 2D surface "slice" of the volume of the scale space.

@Davey very interesting.   I think this is what people have used for this sort of problems before, e.g, this Python module that does something similar.

Alternatively you could do several slices $\sigma^2$ of said space and interpolate between them at every $x,y \in \mathbb x$. This would be along the lines of pyramid technique https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_(image_processing), but more of an approximation of what you want.  Many more implementations of pyramids than scale spaces currently.

This is implemented in DIPlib for 2D and 3D images, not for 1D. It is a brute-force implementation, but is quite efficient. https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/nonlinear.html#dip-AdaptiveGauss-Image-CL-ImageConstRefArray-CL-Image-L-FloatArray-CL-UnsignedArray-CL-dfloat--UnsignedArray-CL-String-CL-String-CL
